# AJAX Contact Form is sending empty parameters?

Tags: php, jquery, post, forms

Not a question I want to ask but I really need another pair of eyes on this one as it must be something silly I am missing.

I have used this same script previously so I've no idea what's going wrong.

This is the frnt end code: http://jsfiddle.net/fU3Q3/1/

And the backend PHP is:

```
<?php 
require("../db.php");

// get the posted values
$email=$_POST['email'];
$password=$_POST['password'];

// now validating the username and password
$sql="SELECT * FROM admin WHERE email='".$email."'";
$result=mysql_query($sql) or die ("No such username exists!");
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);

// if username exists
if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0)
{
// compare the password
if(strcmp($row['password'],$password)==0)
{
    echo "yes";
    // set the session from here
    $_SESSION['email']=$email; 
}
else
    echo "no"; 
}
else
echo "no"; // invalid Login
?>
```

Using firebug, the url that is sent to ajax-login.php seems to be `email=&password=&rand=0.636999888626322` where obviously the bit on the end is the random number.

Any help is much appreciated.

Martin

Comment: Also: you forgot database input escaping.

Comment: Here's some more things that you need to change before production. Password's should at least be stored as hashes, your sessions should be encrypted, sessions should as well contain enough information to compare logins when each page is loaded to ensure that they haven't been hijacked and your num_rows() should compare to 1 not > 0 to add another layer of enforcement to a unique email field (although this should have been checked long ago at user registration)

Comment: this is just for a personal site that I'm tinkering with but I agree about storing passwords as md5 and the `>0` being `==1`. I'm not sure how you encrypt a session though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.post("ajax-login.php",{ email:$("input#email").val(),password:$("input#password").val
(),rand:Math.random() } ,function(data)
```

you have 2 id's of the same type, a div id of email, a input id of email for example, you can not call #email as it will stop at the first occurance

For further explanation... id's without associated class names are considered unique, only 1 id can be used however if you have:

```
<div class='content' id='email'>
<input class='content' id='email'>
```

you can call these in jquery by using following examples:

formal declaration, type > classname '.' > id '#'

```
$("div.content#email");
$("input.content#email");
```

and this will not work without matching the first tag

```
$(".content#email");
$(".content#email");
```

Comment: ah, thanks, I didn't notice the div's with the same id's .... I knew it was going to be something silly. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

as the other said don't share ids and try this:

replace:

```
{ email:$("#email").val(),password:$("#password").val(),rand:Math.random() }
```

with

```
$(this).parents("form").serialize()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sjD9q/

Comment: thanks, if I change it I get `missing : after property id` because I tried to change it to `$('#login_form').serialize()` and got the same error :(

Answer (score 1):

You're password and email inputs share an ID with the parent divs that contain them, if you change the div id's then the form should work.

**NB**: It's bad practice to have multiple ID's of the same name as this will break relevant CSS and Javascript in many browsers.